# Is there a way to conditionalize a C++ macro against the g++ version to work around this static-cast behavior-change between g++ 9.4.0 and 11.3?

Tags: c++, std, stringstream, static-cast

The code below demonstrates that when streaming the return-value from `std::stringstream::operator<<` to a `std::ostream` instance, like `std::cout`, an explicit `static_cast` (from `std::basic_ostream<char>` back to `std::stringstream`) is necessary with *g++ 9.4.0* and causes a compile error with *g++ 11.3*:

```
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#define LOG(x) \
std::cout << (static_cast<std::stringstream&>(std::stringstream{} << x).str()) << std::endl;
//std::cout << ((std::stringstream{} << x).str()) << std::endl;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  LOG("hello, world!");

  return 0;
}
```

```
$ g++ --version && g++ ./main.cpp && ./a.out
g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

hello, world!
$
```

```
$ g++ --version && g++ -g ./main.cpp && ./a.out                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
g++ (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

./main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
./main.cpp:7:15: error: invalid ‘static_cast’ from type ‘std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>’ to type ‘std::stringstream&’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>&’}
    7 | std::cout << (static_cast<std::stringstream&>(std::stringstream{} << x).str()) << std::endl;
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./main.cpp:11:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘LOG’
   11 |   LOG("hello, world!");
      |   ^~~
$
```

And vice-versa: the lack of an explicit `static_cast` causes `g++ 9.4.0` to emit an error and succeeds with `g++ 11.3`:

```
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#define LOG(x) \
std::cout << ((std::stringstream{} << x).str()) << std::endl;
//std::cout << (static_cast<std::stringstream&>(std::stringstream{} << x).str()) << std::endl;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  LOG("hello, world!");

  return 0;
}
```

```
$ g++ --version && g++ ./main.cpp && ./a.out
g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

./main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
./main.cpp:7:42: error: ‘class std::basic_ostream<char>’ has no member named ‘str’
    7 | std::cout << ((std::stringstream{} << x).str()) << std::endl;
      |                                          ^~~
./main.cpp:11:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘LOG’
   11 |   LOG("hello, world!");
      |   ^~~
$
```

```
$ g++ --version && g++ -g ./main.cpp && ./a.out
g++ (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

hello, world!
$
```

This is a source of annoyance, because I need to compile this code in two environments: one with `g++ 9.4.0` and the other with `g++ 11.3`.

**Please help me understand the nature of these compile errors, specifically wrt the discrepancy between *g++ 9.4.0* and *g++ 11.3*:**

- Which compiler version is in the right?
- Is there a preprocessor macro to test the compiler version, by which I can conditionalize the definition of `LOG(x)`?

(I would have assumed that *g++ 11.3* is correct since it is more recent; but this leaves me wondering: why *isn't* the explicit `static_cast` necessary? According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt, the `std::stringstream` insertion operator does indeed return a reference to base-class `basic_ostream`, which has no `str()` function, so I'm puzzled why `std::cout << ((std::stringstream{} << x).str()) << std::endl;` is valid)

Comment: How is `std::cout << ((std::stringstream{} << x).str())` different than `std::cout << x`?

Comment: If you just want to define the macro one way or another based on the g++ version, see [gcc predefined macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html), specifically for `__GNUC__`, `__GNUC_MINOR__`, and `__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__`. As for which compiler version is right, I am interested in hearing with the C++ experts have to say. I do wonder if "which is right" depends on the C++ standard.

Comment: Or, if you want something that will simply just compile on both g++ versions: `#define LOG(x) {std::stringstream ss; ss << (x); std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;}`

Comment: @ShaneBishop Yes, it depends on the standard. This was an issue up to C++11: https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue1203

Comment: @Chad - perhaps this is a better example: `throw std::runtime_error((std::stringstream{} << "hello " << 42).str().c_str());` vs `throw std::runtime_error(static_cast<std::stringstream&>((std::stringstream{} << "hello " << 42)).str().c_str());`

Comment: @ShaneBishop - agreed on your proposed solution; but you may consider my question academic: I ask for curiosity's sake, or for the sake of learning something new about the language's nuances :) if only because something that seems possible/correct within the confines of the language doesn't work. In this case, I'm trying specifically to use a temporary, anonymous `stringstream` object.

Comment: @StoneThrow The issue https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue1203 explains why one was correct in the past, and the other one is now. With the two combined, I'm sure someone could write the full solution. I'm too tired.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
std::cout << (static_cast<std::stringstream&&>(std::stringstream{} << x).str()) << std::endl;
```

Because (std::stringstream{} << x) is not a lvalue.

In fact, clang++ give a better error message:

> cast.cpp:9:2: error: non-const lvalue reference to type
> 'basic_stringstream<...>' cannot bind to a temporary of type
> 'basic_stringstream<...>'